# Generate multiple constructors from fields in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java class in Eclipse that looks like this:

```
public class Assignment {
    public LeftSide leftSide;
    public ArithmeticExpression arithmeticExpression;
    public Location location;
}
```

I want eclipse to generate a separate constructor for each variable like this:

```
public class Assignment {
    public LeftSide leftSide;
    public ArithmeticExpression arithmeticExpression;
    public Location location;

    public Assignment(LeftSide leftSide) {
        this.leftSide = leftSide;
    }

    public Assignment(ArithmeticExpression arithmeticExpression) {
        this.arithmeticExpression = arithmeticExpression;
    }

    public Assignment(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

I know Eclipse has the wonderful feature "Generate constructor using fields" but like the name says, it only seems to be able to generate a single constructor, not all three at once. I know I'm very lazy and feature-greedy but is it possible to generate all three at once?

Comment: Btw forth line: it's location not locatino

Comment: @JClassic that's what you get for fiddling with the code after c/p ;) ..fixed

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to generate all three at once, but you can use the menu to generate these constructors one at a time.

Just check off the specific "field to initialize" each time you open the menu.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough.. I'm explicitly talking about creating multiple constructors at once

Comment: There's no way to create them all at once with Eclipse alone. But you could write a plugin to add this functionality.